# Add an custom attribute to a git commit-object

Tags: git

I found this commit in a public repo. It adds a custom attribute to the committer object. At least that's what it looks like with git show. How can I create such a custom attribute?

[image: Commit from here: https://github.com/gunnihinn/git-commit-mine/commit/0000007b4631d7f2c7812fefc52a7d0b03466b8a]

I know in the repo it says adding is up to the reader and I assumed that you just edit the msg. But I don't understand how he could create his own attributes. Check out the repo for [yourself](https://github.com/gunnihinn/git-commit-mine/commit/0000007b4631d7f2c7812fefc52a7d0b03466b8a).